# serialization exception with datacontract

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

this is what it says:
Type 'ItemType[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfItemType:ItemType' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

the code is pretty basic

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ItemType));
FileStream file = new FileStream("ItemType.xml", FileMode.Create); 
ser.WriteObject(file, itemTypes);
```

the object im trying to serialize is

```
protected static ItemType[] itemTypes = new ItemType[100];
```

derived from the class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "ItemType")]

public class ItemType 
{    
    string name;       
    private int numberOfActions; 

    [DataMember()]
    public int[] codeOfAction = new int[10];
    [DataMember()]
    public int[] recipeType;
    [DataMember()]
    public int[] recipeNum;

    public ItemType()
    {
        this.name = " ";        
        this.recipeType = new int[10];
        this.recipeNum = new int[10];
        this.recipeType[0] = 0;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemName
    {
        get {return name;}
        set { name = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int NumberOfAction
    {
        get { return numberOfActions; }
        set { numberOfActions = value; }  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you serialize an array. But in the parameters passed to the constructor class instead of an array.

Replace

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ItemType));
```

on

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ItemType[]));
```